# MethodInvokingBean question

Tags: spring

I have a method invoking bean which calls a method to perform some sort of initialization on a targetBean and another bean who needs a twitter class albeit initialized.

```
<bean id="twitter" class="twitter4j.Twitter"></bean>

<bean id="twitterInjector"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="twitter"/>
      <property name="targetMethod">
          <value>setOAuthConsumer</value>
      </property>
      <property name="arguments">
         <list>
           <value>consumerKey</value>
           <value>consumerSecret</value>
         </list>
     </property>
</bean>

<bean  id="MyPageController"
       class="com.hardwire.controller.MyPageController">
       <property name="twitter" ref="What should I put here? twitter or
                                                             twitterInjector?/>
       .
       .
       .         
</bean>
```

What should I inject into the MyPageController, twitterInjector or twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodInvokingFactoryBean` - like all other factory beans in Spring - is primarily intended to produce a new bean; in this particular case by invoking a method of some other bean (or class). Your `setOAuthConsumer` method doesn't seem like it would return a bean, so using `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` may not be the best approach in these circumstances.

If I am mistaken and it does return a bean (in which case consider renaming it) and that's the bean you want injected in your controller then you should use `twitterInjector` as ref value. If you really want `twitter` in your controller, then you should use `twitter`.